# Countif formula in excel, but maybe something better can be used than countifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas, countif

[image]

I have a data set of over 40,000 lines. With column A has date of purchase and column C has the customer id. Customers has multiple purchases on same day as shown in image. (Covers 3 month period)

I need figure out how many days the customer made a purchase. End request would be a list of customer ID and how many days they purchase any number of items. I do know there are 154 customer ids.

I was thinking the COUNTIFS formula but I can not get it to work.

Thank you!

I was able to get distinct count using pivot table, but I want to know if there is an formula for this also

Comment: Perhaps unique() to get the list of ID's. Then countifs().

Comment: Please provide the sample data in [Table markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) format so we can reproduce it easely in Excel. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the best way to do it is using Distinct Count, but this are an option:

1. You will need to put the Id and date columns side by side and then use the =UNIQUE formula

let's suppose that Id is in "A" column and Date in "B"

you must create a new table using =UNIQUE(A2:B17, FALSE, FALSE)

**IMPORTANT: you need to pass your data interval. Cannot set the entire column.
the first FALSE argument indicates to excel look for rows and the second FALSE returns the distinct rows once.

[that's my sample database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2kcF.png)

[that's my new table, using UNIQUE formula (my excel is in portuguese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKBOd.png)

As I said, the best way to get distinct days that your costumers bought is using power pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged `array-formulas` I'm assuming that you **don't** have `UNIQUE()` or any other dynamic-array formulae -
[image: Screenshot illustrating possible, but inefficient, legacy solution]

The array formula in the `F2:G2` range is

```
=COUNT(N(VLOOKUP((ROW($1:$15)+44985)&E2,$A$2:$A$29&$C$2:$C$29,1,FALSE)))
```

and it is important to note that, prior to entering the formula, you must have *more than one cell selected* - if you have only one cell selected when you confirm the formula with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> then the formula will only return a result of 1

44985 is the Excel version of Feb 28th such that the expression `(ROW($1:$15)+44985)` generates all 15 distinct days covered in the screenshot - with 40,000 rows in your dataset I strongly urge you to use a pivot table, particularly when, in your context, the minimum update frequency for your data cannot be more than once per day.